# Deploy Tensorflow on a server without installing using Slurm Manager

Tags: python, server, tensorflow

I would like to install Tensorflow on a High Performance Computing Cluster that use Slurm Manager. I do not have The admin right so I want to deploy Tensorflow without installing it. However I cannot find any informations about this. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the second half of your question, see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826736/running-tensorflow-on-a-slurm-cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to install TensorFlow if you do not have admin (root) privileges is to install it in a virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

[Full instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/v0.6.0/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_install) are available on the TensorFlow website.

Comment: fyi: link is dead